# Owl Carousel Fade transition on IE 7+

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm using the fabulous Owl Carousel for my website and more specificaly the "fade" effect.
You can see a demo right here : http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html

Pictures of my carousel "fade" fine on Chrome but on IE, they "slide" instead.
On the official website, it is said :

> "Important! CSS3 transition works only in modern browsers that support
>   CSS3 translate3d methods and only with single item on screen."

Thus, I looked for a hack and found this :

```
#monElement {
opacity: .4; /* for all modern webcrawlers */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE6, IE7, and IE8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40)"; /* IE8 only */
}
```

But... it doesn't work either.
An idea of what it could be ?

Thank you

Comment: This is not a question about the Web Ontology Language, and should not have been tagged with [tag:owl].

Answer (score 0):

Using DXImageTransform to achieve this effect on IE7+8 (deprecated from 9) requires some Javascript also. [MS Technet visual filters and transitions reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provides examples of how to achieve this. Obviously, these examples will only work in IE 7 or 8.

For example:

```
<script>
var bToggle = 0;
function fnToggle() {
    oDiv.filters[0].Apply();                   

    // After setting Apply, changes to the oDiv object 
    //  are not displayed until Play is called.
    if (bToggle) {                                                        
        bToggle = 0;
        oDiv.style.backgroundColor="gold";}
    else {
        bToggle = 1;
        oDiv.style.backgroundColor="blue";}  
    oDiv.filters[0].Play();
}
</script>

<button onclick="fnToggle()">Toggle Transition</button><br/><br/>

<div id="oDiv" style="height:250px; width:250px; background-color: gold;
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade( 
                duration=2);">
</div>
```